Can a person be adopted into a tribe?
Related: Does 2 Samuel 6:23 and Samuel 21:8 affirm that you could be adopted into tribal affiliation?
The question linked above asks whether certain Biblical passages support a theory that one can be adopted into tribal affiliation, and it seems dubious that those passages actually do that. Regardless of what the passages quoted in the above question support, is it possible via any means for a person to be adopted into membership into one of the twelve tribes?
For a hypothetical, suppose Reuven is a convert to Judaism and thus lacks tribal membership (or, perhaps, he was born Jewish to a convert father who lacked any tribal membership to pass down). He feels a strong connection to the tribe of Dan and would like to become a member of that tribe. He (somehow) finds a few members of the tribe who are interested in supporting or sponsoring him for tribal adoption. Is this possible? Would being adopted (as in traditional parent/child adoption) by a male member of the tribe be enough to grant tribal membership to the adoptee? Is admission of outsiders to tribal membership a centralized process administered by tribal leaders pursuant to halacha and tribal bylaws? Can a beit din composed of members of the tribe admit a Jew of no tribe into tribal membership in a similar way that a beit din of Jews can admit a Gentile into Jewishness?
To be clear, why a person would want to gain tribal membership in this day and age or why a tribe would want to admit outsiders into tribal membership are not in scope - this is a hypothetical and I'm curious if there is even a way to make this happen.

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114051/why-was-the-blasphemer-not-allowed-to-dwell-among-dan.

@Harel13 I thought of that too, but that itself doesn't prove that being adopted isn't possible. Perhaps the thought of seeking formal adoption never occurred to the blasphemer. Maybe he thought so much that he was already a member that he considered seeking adoption to be offensive and an affront to his dignity. Perhaps he applied for tribal membership through the standard process and was rejected.

If you'll read through the entire question you'll notice that I cited the case of Yair b. Menashe who was actually a member of the tribe of Judah but was apparently adopted into the tribe of his mother's side, Menashe (hence his nickname "b. Menashe").
